# MySQL INSERT INTO single column from a SELECT query pulling data from two other tables - throwing #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 2 error

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, vlookup, insert-into

I've got one col (state_not_allowed) in `TABLE` vendor_product where I'm trying to insert values from product_catalog_varchar.value - but only if there's a sku in vendor_product that matches a sku in product_catalog where product_catalog's id equals product_catalog_varchar's id and product_catalog_varchar's attribute id = 523.

I'm basically trying to do the MySQL equivalent of an Excel VLOOPUP. I need the result of the following query:

```
SELECT product_catalog_varchar.value
FROM product_catalog_varchar
JOIN product_catalog 
ON product_catalog.id = product_catalog_varchar.id
JOIN vendor_product
ON vendor_product.sku = product_catalog.sku
AND product_catalog_varchar.attribute_id = 523
```

To be inserted in to column state_not_allowed, where the sku in vendor_product = the sku in product_catalog.

I've done some research on `INSERT INTO`, here and on Google in general. Looks like a lot of the instruction out there is on simplier queries so I haven't been able to find a decent model to figure out what to do. I can tell you that this query doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO vendor_product(`state_not_allowed`)
SELECT product_catalog_varchar.value
FROM product_catalog_varchar
JOIN product_catalog 
ON product_catalog.id = product_catalog_varchar.id
JOIN vendor_product
ON vendor_product.sku = product_catalog.sku
AND product_catalog_varchar.attribute_id = 523
```

It throws the following error: #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 2

And if I got to vendor_product and look, instead of simply inserting values in to state_not_allowed, it's creating a whole new row (with no data). Clearly, I'm misunderstanding in a fundamental sense here. Help me out? Thanks folks.

Comment: why do you have this 'product_catalog.id = product_catalog_varchar.id' in WHERE clause if you are same for first JOIN?

Comment: Good question. I got distracted while writing the query I guess. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

This query shows the general idea of what you want to do.

```
insert into table2
(field1)
select distinct field1
from table1
where field1 in
(select field1
from table1
except 
select field1
from table2)
```

The details vary from RDBMS to RDBMS.  For example, Oracle uses the keyword minus instead of except.  Your MySql documentation will help you with the details.

Note that while it's tempting to simplify this by using "not in" that construct tends to be slow.

Comment: I'm following along with your query here, but I'm a bit confused as to where in here I'd be cross-referencing the skus to make sure the values in vendor_product (or in your example, table2) were assigned to the correct rows.

Comment: The example shows how to insert rows unless you already have them.  Checking the accuracy of the data is a different question.  Perhaps adding more conditions to the where clause will do the trick.  Perhaps adding a where clause to the top half of the subquery will give you what you need.  You are the one who knows your database, not me.